# npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/n'

Tags: node.js, npm

❯ npm install -g n

npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n

npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir

'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/n'

npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir

'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/n'] {

npm ERR!   errno: -13,

npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',

npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/n'

npm ERR! }

npm ERR!

npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.

npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access

this file as the current user

npm ERR!

npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please

double-check the

npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running

npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/peywan/.npm/_logs/2022-03-17T00_34_38_978Z-

debug-0.log
   ~                                                 243 ✘  at 01:34:39 

Comment: well this is saying that you dont have permission to write to /usr/local/lib/node_modules - its pretty clear

Comment: but how can I solve this?

Comment: im the admin of this computer, and there's only 1 admin on this computer

Comment: Try `sudo npm install -g n` for a simple fix, but you should refer to npm's docs for a better fix

Comment: but how can I solve this so I don't have to use the "sudo" all the time... because most of the things doesn't work without sudo

Comment: If you get here coming from mac you can easily fix with "brew install node". I think installing node using the package uses a user that is not in your computer.

Answer (score -2):

I solved the issue by running the command with sudo

```
sudo npm install -g "module_name"
```